# Python subprocess.check_output()

Tags: subprocess

```
mystring = subprocess.check_output(["sudo iwlist wlan0 scan"], universal_newlines=True)
word = 'Devsign2G'
print (mystring)
print (word)

if word in str(mystring):
    print ('success')
```

-error message-

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 52, in 
        mystring = subprocess.check_output(["sudo iwlist wlan0 scan"], universal_newlines=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
        process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

> what is the problem?

The `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` refers to the subprocess command which is to be executed.

The program arguments must be passed individually in the sequence, so change

```
["sudo iwlist wlan0 scan"]
```

to

```
["sudo", "iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is using a file called "subprocess" located here: /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py

But the file or directory isn't there. You can change the dir or put the file in the correct folder.

If it's an packaged. Did you install the package with pip or sth? Is it imported?

Comment: This package is a built-in package in Python 2.7.

I entered the command(sudo apt-get install subprocess) but the answer is "E: Invalid operation subprocess"

Comment: The package is already installed, as it can be seen from the traceback. The file subprocess is there, so this is not the source of the problem.